# JQuery in ASP.NET - Form Validation Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, validation

It's not working at all and I'm not sure why. Ideally I'd like to have all the errors pop up in a modal dialog box. But right now I can't even get it to work normally. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Frame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body runat="server" id="bodyLogin">
<div runat="server" id="frameLogin">
    <form runat="server" id="formLogin">
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkboxRemember" />
        <div><span id="un">Username</span><div id="forgotUsername">?</div><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textUsername" Name="username" /></div>
        <div><span id="pw">Password</span><div id="forgotPassword">?</div><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textPassword" Name="password" TextMode="Password" /></div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonLogin" Text="L" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonRegister" Text="R" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Errors" style="display:none;"><ul></ul></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#formLogin").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required:true,
            minlength:3,
            maxlength:15
        },
        password: {
            required:true,
            minlength:6,
            maxlength:15
        },
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Username is required.",
            minlength: "Username minimum length is 3 characters.",
            maxlength: "Username maxumum length is 15 characters."
        },
        password: {
            required: "Password is required.",
            minlength: "Password minumum length is 6 characters.",
            maxlength: "Password maximum length is 15 characters."
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

EDIT: I tried both...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Frame_Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.Frames.Frame_Login" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

and...

```
    $("#<%= formLogin.ClientID %>").validate({
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Name property from TextBox controls. All the way your value will be overrided with autogenerated one. And use script below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= formLogin.ClientID %>").validate({
        rules: {
            '<%= textUsername.ClientID %>': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15
            },

            '<%= textPassword.ClientID %>': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 15
            }
        },

        messages: {
            '<%= textUsername.ClientID %>': {
                required: "Username is required.",
                minlength: "Username minimum length is 3 characters.",
                maxlength: "Username maxumum length is 15 characters."
            },

            '<%= textPassword.ClientID %>': {
                required: "Password is required.",
                minlength: "Password minumum length is 6 characters.",
                maxlength: "Password maximum length is 15 characters."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked splendidly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` if using .NET 4, other wise get the `ClientID` and stick that in the javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form has runat="server", you need to use the asp client id in your jQuery.

Like this:

```
$("#<%= formLogin.ClientID %>").validate({
//etc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to help either.